# Agetty Serial Modem

Tags: linux

Hi I have a problem with Agetty, I have an old minitel 1200/75 baud terminal, I have tried different configurations to connect with a 56k modem in v23 bell mode, the server closes the connection
maybe init chat modem problem?
thank you
/etc/mgetty+sendfax/mgetty.config
port ttyS5
speed 1200
direct no
data-only yes
toggle-dtr yes
need-dsr yes
port-owner root
port-group wheel
port-mode 0660
login-prompt ''
login-time 60
term minitel1b-80
login-env-ttyprompt-hack yes
init-chat "" "ATM0E0B2\r" "OK"
gettydefs 1200v23

/sbin/mgetty -D ttyS5 1200v23

no working modem hangout line.
Thanks

Comment: This question is _very_ difficult to understand. Please start by using Markdown markup for [code and code blocks (preformatted text)](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) to clarify your commands, code, configuration files and whatever else is in there. Also, what version of Linux are you using? If it's a modern one, this would probably be better posted in the [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) since the problem is with your configuration of that, not the modem.

Comment: This has been [reposted on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/705107/86440).